# Excel VBA - save current web address to use in another sub routine

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Quick question I hope there is an easy answer.
I have a sub routine that navigates through a webpage. "Sub Navigate()"

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
```

and so on.....

This part works fine and I successfully navigate through IE as needed. My next step comes from a separate sub routine "Sub copyimage()" I have designed where I pull images off the active page. However I cannot figure out how to use the open webpage for this.

The "Sub Copyimage()" sub works if I navigate directly to the URL within this sub. But I want to be able to get there from the work of my "Sub Navigate()" code.

I would like to be able to call the Copyimage() subroutine from the navigate() subroutine.

Please help

Here is full code from the first sub:

```
Sub FMSWebsite()
Dim strURL
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
strURL = "https://functionalmovement.com/login?return=%2F"
ie.Navigate strURL
ie.Visible = True
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop
ie.Document.forms(0).all("Username").Value = Worksheets("Cover").Range("E8")
ie.Document.forms(0).all("Password").Value = Worksheets("Cover").Range("E10")
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

ie.Document.forms(0).submit
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
ie.Navigate ("http://functionalmovement.com/pro/clients")
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop


ie.Document.forms(1).all("gvClients$DXFREditorcol1").Value = Worksheets("Template").Range("X2")
ie.Document.forms(1).all("gvClients$DXFREditorcol1").Select

SendKeys String:="{enter}", Wait:=True

Application.Wait (now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

Dim e
For Each e In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("strong")
If e.innerText = "Client Workouts" Then
e.ParentElement.Click
Exit For
End If
Next

Application.Wait (now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

For Each e In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
If e.innerText = "Create a New Workout" Then
e.ParentElement.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

For Each e In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
If e.innerText = "NEXT" Then
e.ParentElement.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Set goBtn = ie.Document.getElementById("newscreen")
goBtn.Click

Application.Wait (now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop
```

Fast Forward some code it ends like so:

```
For Each e In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
If e.innerText = "Complete" Then
e.ParentElement.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop
For Each e In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
If e.innerText = "View Assigned Workout" Then
e.ParentElement.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
End Sub
```

My next sub starts with

```
Sub findimageA ()
For Each Elem In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
If Elem.getAttribute("title") = "Step 1" Then
```

How do I reference the web address I ended with in the first sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have in `Navigate()` something like:

```
Dim ieDocument as Object
```

which represent a web page (web document). If so, you need to create `Copyimage()` subroutine with argument, like this:

```
Sub Copyimage(ieDocImages as object)
```

and call this sub from previous one passing document (`ieDocument`) as a parameter:

```
Call Copyimage(ieDocument)
```

or do something similar depending of variables you use.

**EDIT, based on additional code in question**

First sub- add the following line before `End Sub` or before you terminate `ie object`:

```
Call findimagA(ie.Document)
```

and change the second sub as follows:

```
Sub findimageA(ieDocument As Object)
For Each Elem In ieDocument.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

*Not tested but I'm sure it is ok.*

Comment: I open my webpage with the following code: `Dim strURL
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
strURL = "https://functionalmovement.com/login?return=%2F"
IE.Navigate strURL
IE.Visible = True
Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4)
  DoEvents
Loop`

Comment: And what is next? Add your complete code to your question

Comment: I added my coding. Sorry for being so vague. I hope this gives you better insite in to what I am asking.